# illegal floating point format on OSx but not Linux

Tags: c++, macos

Using `g++` compiler, the code below throws the `Illegal floating-point format` error on a Macbook pro, but it runs without error on Fedora compiled with both `g++` and `clang++`.

Question: why would it not work on Mac and is there a way to make it work on Mac

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

double stringToReal(std::string str) {
   std::istringstream stream(str);
   double value;
   stream >> value >> std::ws;
   if (stream.fail() || !stream.eof()) {
      std::cerr << "stringToReal: Illegal floating-point format (" << str << ")";
   }
   return value;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << stringToReal("1.457460091727E12");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most probably default locale thing. Try `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C")`.

Comment: @Lol4t0 I added this `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` to the first line of  `main` func and got same error

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11?   If so, what happens if you try `stod` instead of a `stringstream`?   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an OS X bug to me. Trying to read `std::ws` at EOF is setting the fail bit on the stream, but it shouldn't. If you append any whitespace to the string, the error goes away.

#### UPDATE

Actually, it may be a Fedora bug. According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws), `std::ws` “Behaves as an `UnformattedInputFunction`”, and it says this about `UnformattedInputFunction`:

> if `eofbit` or `badbit` are set on the input stream, sets the `failbit` as well, and if exceptions on `failbit` are enabled in this input stream's exception mask, throws `ios_base::failure`.

Reading into `value` sets the eof bit, so then reading into `std::ws` should in fact set the fail bit.

Comment: ok, thank you, I can get that code to run by adding whitespace like this `"1.457460091727E12 " ` but the function is actually in a library (not a single file) included by a program (this stand alone file in the OP was created for the purpose of the OP only) How would you alter the function `stringToReal` so that the application?

Comment: my previous comment was made before your edit. Is there anything I can do to the function to get my application running? (it's code created by a uni prof for learning purposes, nothing majorly consequential if something small is altered to make it run)

Comment: The function returns the correct result either way. It's just that sometimes it also prints a message to standard error.